# Как подключаться по sshfs к хранилищу

Tags: linux, centos, sshfs

Есть сервер с CentOS 6.4 и удаленное sftp-хранилище (без Линукса)
Подключаюсь к нему командой:

```
sshfs пользователь@адрес: /var/spool/asterisk/ftpserver -o allow_other,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=30,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,nonempty
```

Потом надо вводить пароль.
Как можно подключаться автоматически, не вводя вручную пароль? Например в curlftpfs есть такая функция:

```
-o user=юзер:пароль
```

Но curlftpfs показался мне очень медленным.

Пробовал скопировать rsa ключ на хранилище командой:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub '-p 22 юзер@адрес'
```

Но выходит такая ошибка:

```
exec request failed on channel 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub '-p 22 юзер@адрес'
>   exec request failed on channel 0

вполне логично, если позволяют только *sftp*.

если тамошний ssh-сервер вообще позволяет использовать ключи, попробуйте добавить их вручную:

1. примонтируйте домашний каталог этого пользователя куда-нибудь в пустой каталог:

   ```
   $ sshfs пользователь@адрес: /локальный/пустой/каталог
   ```
2. создайте в нём каталог `.ssh`:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /локальный/пустой/каталог/.ssh
   ```
3. добавьте в файл `authorized_keys` в этом каталоге ваш публичный ключ:

   ```
   $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | tee -a /локальный/пустой/каталог/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
4. сделайте каталог `.ssh` и его содержимое недоступным другим пользователям:

   ```
   $ chmod -R go= /локальный/пустой/каталог/.ssh
   ```
5. отмонтируйте домашний каталог:

   ```
   $ fusermount -u /локальный/пустой/каталог
   ```

теперь попробуйте перемонтировать то, что вам требуется.

если всё равно запросит пароль, то, скорее всего, тамошний ssh-сервер либо вообще не поддерживает авторизацию по ключу, либо она запрещена (для данного пользователя).

тогда можно попробовать передать пароль через *stdin*. согласно `man sshfs`, программа должна понимать опцию `password_stdin`:

```
$ echo пароль | sshfs -o password_stdin,другие-опции ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
echo 'password' | sshfs user@remote.host:/somedir /somemydir -o password_stdin
```

Спасибо!